# AngularJS table column sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing table config.json file to controll table columns filter, sort ect.
I have a column example, i need to disable sorting for name column in ng-click.
**disabled || ...** but sorting was still working.

I need to use Anchor tag and dont want to change it for button.

controller file

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('view1', []);

app.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http) {

    $scope.orderByField = 'imie';
    $scope.reverseSort = false;
    $scope.query = {};
    $http.get('config.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.conf = data;
    });

    $http.get('data.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.pacjenci = data;
    });
    $scope.add = function () {
        $location.path('/view2');
    };

    $scope.edit = function () {
        $location.path('/view2');
    };

    $scope.remove = function (imie) {
        var index = -1;
        var pacArr = eval($scope.pacjenci);
        for (var i = 0; i < pacArr.length; i++) {
            if (pacArr[i].imie === imie) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        $scope.pacjenci.splice(index, 1);
    };

}]);
```

```html
<form name="form" ng-submit="add()" role="form">
    <section ng-app="view1" ng-controller="View1Ctrl">
        <div>
            Wyszukaj: <label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
        </label>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
 <th ng-hide = "conf.imie.visible"><a href=""
  ng-click="orderByField='imie';reverseSort = !reverseSort"> Imie </a></th>
                <th ng-hide = "conf.nazwisko.visible"><a href=""
                       ng-click="orderByField='nazwisko'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                    Nazwisko </a></th>
                <th ng-hide = "conf.pesel.visible"><a href=""
                       ng-click="orderByField='pesel'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                    Pesel </a></th>
                <th ng-hide = "conf.kraj.visible"><a href=""
                       ng-click="orderByField='kraj'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                    Kraj </a></th>
                <th ng-hide = "conf.wojewodztwo.visible"><a href=""
                       ng-click="orderByField='wojewodztwo'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                    Województwo </a></th>
                <th ng-hide = "conf.powiat.visible"><a href=""
                       ng-click="orderByField='powiat'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                    Powiat </a></th>
                <th ng-hide = "conf.miejscowosc.visible"><a href=""
                       ng-click="orderByField='miejscowosc'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                    Miejscowość </a></th>
                <th ng-hide = "conf.kod.visible"><a href=""
                       ng-click="orderByField='kod'; reverseSort = !reverseSort"> Kod
                    Pocztowy </a></th>
                <th ng-hide = "conf.ulica.visible"><a href=""
                       ng-click="orderByField='ulica'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                    Ulica </a></th>
                <th ng-hide = "conf.nrdomu.visible"><a href=""
                       ng-click="orderByField='nrdomu'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                    Nr Domu </a></th>
                <th><a> Edycja </a></th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="pac in pacjenci|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort|filter:searchText">
                <td ng-hide = "conf.imie.visible">{{pac.imie}}</td>
                <td ng-hide = "conf.nazwisko.visible">{{pac.nazwisko}}</td>
                <td ng-hide = "conf.pesel.visible">{{pac.pesel}}</td>
                <td ng-hide = "conf.kraj.visible">{{pac.kraj}}</td>
                <td ng-hide = "conf.wojewodztwo.visible">{{pac.wojewodztwo}}</td>
                <td ng-hide = "conf.powiat.visible">{{pac.powiat}}</td>
                <td ng-hide = "conf.miejscowosc.visible">{{pac.miejscowosc}}</td>
                <td ng-hide = "conf.kod.visible">{{pac.kod}}</td>
                <td ng-hide = "conf.ulica.visible">{{pac.ulica}}</td>
                <td ng-hide = "conf.nrdomu.visible">{{pac.nrdomu}}</td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Usuń"
                           class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="remove(pac.imie)"/>
                    <input type="button" value="Edytuj"
                           class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit(pac.imie)"/>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Dodaj</button>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

Comment: `doesn't work` isn't a proper problem statement

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit?. Question is not very clear. I couldn't even find the name column. If you don't want to sort the name column, simply remove the link to sort. Or is something else your requirement?

Comment: e.g i have 

**<th><a href=""
  ng-click="orderByField='surname'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" >Surname</a></th>**

i need to control sorting from json config file (if someone need to use sort or don't need it will be specified in json). Dont want to delete sorting from source code only steer it through json data.